# Need to display a pop up if we are selecting a step response for a workitem in IBM Filenet workplace application

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, filenet-workplace

I am having a requirement where if am selecting a step response for a workitem in workflow map , i need  to restrict it to a data field for taking that action.
For example if am having a step name as'XYZ' and i am selecting the step response' ABC' it should restrict the workitem to be routed to the next step in the workflow by any pop-up window or any alert window in IBM workplace application. I should be able to route the workitem to next step by selecting the step response 'ABC" when the step name is not 'XYZ'

Is this possible in workplace application to achieve this.

I know in IBM Case manager we can restrict the workitem from routing it to the next step with the script adapters in page level. Similarly is there way to achieve this in Workplace application also at the workflow level or something. Please advice.

I have tried adding a condition along with the step response to achieve this. But the workitem is getting terminated if doesn't match the condition.
For example. I have addition the condition as ' All(ABC) and Stepname<>'XYZ' in the conditional route in workflow map. But if i override the condition the workitem is getting terminated.

Comment: did you achieve this?

Comment: No i couldn't able to achieve this yet. Any idea?